# Proving an Automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}_n$

Tags: group-theory

Suppose $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $n\geq$2. Let $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $(m,n)=1$.

Define $\gamma:\mathbb{Z}_n\to\mathbb{Z}_n$ by $\gamma(k)=km\quad mod\,{n}$

Prove $\gamma\in{Aut(\mathbb{Z}_n)}$

I've been able to show that $\gamma$ is a bijection, but I'm having problems satisfying the homomorphic property. Here is what I've thought of doing first.

Let $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}_n$ then we have that $\gamma(ab)=abm(mod\,n)$. But $\gamma(a)\gamma(b)=abm^2(mod\,n)$. So it looks like $\gamma(ab)\neq\gamma(a)\gamma(b)$. I've tried to multiply by 1 ($=ms+nt$ for some $s,t\in\mathbb{Z}$), but this just added variables that I could not remove, nor force to equate. I've tried rewriting m as a linear combination of n,s,t,1 but this also didn't do much to help. I've tried rewriting mod as a LC of the residue and n, but this didn't produce any results. I've currently ran out of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is an additive group. That is, you want
$$
\gamma(a) + \gamma(b) = \gamma(a+b).
$$
So what you have realized is that $\gamma$ is not a ring-homomorphism. Consider, for example, the case where $n=3, m = 2$. Then $\gamma(1) = 2$. And 
$$2 = \gamma(1) = \gamma(1\cdot 1) \neq \gamma(1)\cdot \gamma(1) = 2\cdot 2 = 1.$$

Comment: Oh crap, that is what I'm doing wrong. I've been treating it like a multiplicative group. No wonder it wasn't working out.

Comment: @DrkVenom: That happens :)